# What's the risk of leaving VPP/MCLR floating?

Tags: microcontroller, pic, programmer, icsp

In the microchip [PM3 ICSP design guide](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/51474a.pdf), this diagram is shown to demonstrate a typical implementation of ICSP:

[image]

Here, the `MCLR/VPP` pin is pulled to 5V during normal operation, but isolated when the high voltage for programming is supplied.

A similar setup is shown in [this document](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/31028a.pdf). But I've also seen quite a few circuits taht completely omit this feature and just leave `MCLR/VPP` floating when no programmer is connected, like this:

[image]

Why should I not do it like that? What possible negative effect could this have on the operation of my circuit?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not 'floating' in the second circuit, that particular PIC has an internal pull-up.

[image]

You should read the [datasheet](http://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/40001639B.pdf) for the particular processor you are using. It's only 404 pages, a trifle compared to more modern processors.

---

Edit:

If there was no pullup- what would happen: Bad things- it would float around and might reset the micro or not depending on the phase of the moon and how you breath on the PCB (leakages). If you were lucky it would not work at all from the start.

Some PICs can have the pin re-purposed as an input, in which case that floating around wouldn't have a huge negative effect unless the pin is non-Schmitt trigger, in which case it could cause excessive current draw, more quickly draining a battery, for example.

It's unlikely to cause any *physical* damage in any case, but it could cause some problems that appeared to be random and might be hard to troubleshoot (especially if they got blamed on firmware).

Comment: While I'm not using the one in the picture, mine also has an internal pull-up, I must've missed that. I'd still be interested in what'd happen if that pull-up wasn't there, though.

Comment: See added comments above

Answer (score 3):

If your PIC doesn't have an internal pullup and you don't provide an external one the best you can hope for is that your program will run sometimes.

Without any pullup at all the chip will constantly be resetting at random depending on how many cats are nearby or what underwear you have on.

Answer (score 1):

Leaving high impedance inputs floating is bad practice.  A floating pin is not guaranteed to be in either state, and worse can oscillate between states  sometimes at high frequencies.  This can cause noise, unstable operation, high power usage, and a number of hard to troubleshoot issues.  In this case if the pin drifts low your processor will reset unexpectedly.

Also with many circuits RESET must rise and fall within a certain amount of time as specified in the datasheet.  Too slow or too fast might fail to properly reset all portions of the device.  This may leave it in a non-running or unsafe state.